# .format () into a python dictionary

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I need to scrape all the comments from an online newspaper article. Comments are loaded through an API:

```
https://api-graphql.lefigaro.fr/graphql?id=widget-comments_prod_commentsQuery2_a54719015f409774c55c77471444274cc461e7ee30bcbe03c8449e39ae15b16c&variables={%22id%22:%22bGVmaWdhcm8uZnJfXzYwMjdkODk4LTJjZWQtMTFlYi1hYmNlLTMyOGIwNDdhZjcwY19fQXJ0aWNsZQ==%22,%22page%22:2}
```

Therefore I am using requests to get its content:

```
url = "https://api-graphql.lefigaro.fr/graphql?id=widget-comments_prod_commentsQuery2_a54719015f409774c55c77471444274cc461e7ee30bcbe03c8449e39ae15b16c"

params = "variables={%22id%22:%22bGVmaWdhcm8uZnJfXzYwMjdkODk4LTJjZWQtMTFlYi1hYmNlLTMyOGIwNDdhZjcwY19fQXJ0aWNsZQ==%22,%22page%22:2}"

response = requests.get(url, params).json()

print(json.dumps(response, indent=4))
```

But what I need is to create a **for loop** so I can get every comments since only 10 comments are displayed at a time.

I can't find a way. I tried to use .format() with params like that:

```
 params = "variables={%22id%22:%22bGVmaWdhcm8uZnJfXzYwMjdkODk4LTJjZWQtMTFlYi1hYmNlLTMyOGIwNDdhZjcwY19fQXJ0aWNsZQ==%22,%22page%22:{page_numb}}".format("page_numb":2)
```

But I get a SyntaxError.

Comment: Did change my code accordingly but no I have this error: `KeyError: '%22id%22'`

Comment: Please write it as an answer so I can vote for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.format` doesn't work with key-value pairs. Try `"...{page_num}".format(page_num="2")`.

Also, since the `{` and `}` characters are part of the query payload, you'll have to escape them. `{` becomes `{{` and `}` becomes `}}`. For example, `"{hello {foo}}".format("foo": "world")` becomes `"{{hello {foo}}}".format(foo="world")`. You'll also have to decode the url-encoded string:

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

params = unquote("variables={{%22id%22:%22bGVmaWdhcm8uZnJfXzYwMjdkODk4LTJjZWQtMTFlYi1hYmNlLTMyOGIwNDdhZjcwY19fQXJ0aWNsZQ==%22,%22page%22:{page_numb}}}".format(page_numb=2))
```